# Installing Omnipay - Windows 8 / EasyPHP / CodeIgniter

Tags: omnipay, ci-merchant

I'm having trouble installing Omnipay

I'm running EasyPHP 13.1 on Windows 8 - this works fine - I develop websites in CodeIgniter, Zend, Symfony and Cake - that is all fine

One of the websites I'm building needs PayPal, but might switch to another payment solution later. Omnipay looks ideal as will allow an easy switch later. But I can't get the Omnipay code via Composer.

Omnipay should be installed via Composer. That means installing cURL in Windows to install Composer to install Omnipay so that I can get the source code for a couple of files. If I'm going to install cURL, maybe I should install GNUBash? And now I'm going round in circles for the sake of a couple of files.

Is there an easier way?

Comment: Omnipay/Common depends on Guzzle 3.1, which requires curl, so I don't think it's possible without curl.

Comment: Finally downloaded it by installing xampp then composer and then downloading it using the php command. All files are now in C:/xampp/php/vendor/. Looking at the code, files require (depend on) AbstractGateway which requires Symfony files. Poor. Very poor.

Comment: Hooking up to a gateway should be a simple process. I've done it hundreds of times. Downloading / installing Omnipay is a pig of a job. If you're lucky enough to get hold of the code, it's a huge mess - far too complex with far too many dependencies for something so simple. What's with the Symfony dependencies? Do I want to convert Codeigniter or Cake projects to Symfony? Or do I want to add Symfony components to other MVC frameworks? Or do I want to remove Symfony dependencies?

Comment: Personally, I think far quicker and easier to stick with simple code. It's lean, mean and it works. Omnipay is just a heavy workload for something that should be very simple.